# best way to save sessionStorage before a header

Tags: javascript, php, header, sessionstorage

I want to save a sessionStorage item if the rowcount happens to be 0, I know I shouldn't be echoing anything before a header, hence, please let me know what is the best way to set the sessionStorage before headering on this conditions. Only js and php, dont want to use jquery. Thanks in advance !

```
                <?php
                $admin_table = "admin_table";
                $show_all_admins = "SELECT * FROM $admin_table";
                $show_all_admins_query = mysqli_query($conn, $show_all_admins);
                $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($show_all_admins_query);
                if($rowcount == 0 ){
                    mysqli_close($conn);
                    echo'<script>sessionStorage.setItem("admin_sessn", "admins");</script>';
                    header('Location: http://localhost/littlesidegym.php');
                    exit();
                    }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to handle the redirect in javascript instead of PHP

```
<script>
    sessionStorage.setItem("admin_sessn", "admins");
    window.location = 'http://localhost/littlesidegym.php';
</script>
```